# Scrollbar event handling, how to keep number grabbed static

Tags: java, event-handling, scrollbar

As the title suggests I have a program with a scrollbar interface. The problem is that the program uses the same three scrollbars for four sets of different numbers, once the change has been made to another set of numbers the scrollbar remains on the same values from the previous set of numbers

```
        float RedAmount1 = lightDimmer1.getValue();
        float GreenAmount1 = lightDimmer2.getValue();
        float BlueAmount1 = lightDimmer3.getValue();

        diffuseSwitch[0] = RedAmount1;          
        diffuseSwitch[1] = GreenAmount1;
        diffuseSwitch[2] = BlueAmount1;

        float StoreColours1[] = {RedAmount1,GreenAmount1,BlueAmount1};

        int StoreColourRed = (int)StoreColours1[0];
        int StoreColourGreen = (int)StoreColours1[1];
        int StoreColourBlue = (int)StoreColours1[2];

        if(diffuseSwitch[0] != StoreColourRed)
        {
         lightDimmer1.setValue(StoreColourRed);
        }
```

This piece of code is placed within a scrollbars event handling section so the number am trying to compare float StoreColourRed and diffuseSwitch[0] keep being changed to the values of the latest set of numbers instead of keeping the previous set of values.

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to build your own `JColorChooser`?

Comment: uhh not quite it is a system to manipulate the colours for four sets of lights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a very simple class to hold your values, for example:

```
private static class MyColor {
    float red, green, blue;
}
```

You should be able to use [`getValueIsAdjusting()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/BoundedRangeModel.html#getValueIsAdjusting()) and [`setValueIsAdjusting()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/BoundedRangeModel.html#setValueIsAdjusting(boolean)) to determine when the values are stable. You may also want to us [`JRadioButton`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html) or [`JComboBox`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) to select which set of values is being manipulated.

Addendum: I carelessly assumed [`JSlider`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html) when reading the question. Also, adjusting is probably irrelevant. [`JTabbedPane`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) is another choice for selecting which set of values is being manipulated.